# URL Routing to page with same name

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, routes

I have a currently existing site with URL re-writing enabled using ISAPI Rewrite and IIRF files, the problem is it's causing a lot of problems, both for site development / maintenance and because of continuous errors on the server.

Because of this I'm looking to replace it with .Net 4.0's URL Routing.

I'm having two problems with this, first, the current routing rules are set up so that the page being routed to is simply the re-written URL with the file extension appended to the end.

So `www.site.com/page/` would become `www.site.com/page.aspx`

The second problem is that certain re-written URL's actually point to physical files within sub-folders on the website using the same logic as above.

So `www.site.com/folder/page/` would redirect to `www.site.com/folder/page.aspx`

I've read through [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx) and created custom IRouteHandler and IHttpHander implemented classes, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

I've tried a few different things, mainly related to variables in the URL and trying to redirect to them, but I'm not sure that's the right way for me to go.

I'm not posting code because all I have at the moment is pretty much the example code from the link above.

I've implemented basic routing on another site where a single page uses a variable in the URL to grab the relevant content out of a database, and that seemed simple enough, but this is making my head spin, I'm sure it shouldn't be this complicated.

Comment: First things first, which problems do you have with the standard rewrite modules? What are the errors you are talking about? It is hard to believe you have to implement your own Route- and HttpHandler for some basic rewrites...

Comment: Ah, sorry, wasn't too clear there. I didn't have to implement my own Route and HttpHandlers for the basic routing I've done, that was purely using a selection of MapPageRoute RouteCollection methods

Comment: The custom Route and HttpHandler classes were mainly because I was following the link in the question to try and learn more about routing and what I was doing wrong.